# Update Record of one table While FETCHING value From other table using CURSOR in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to update `designation_id` in table `Employee` by fetching the value of `designation_id` from `designation` table where name of designation in designation table equal to name of designation in employee table 
[Following code is just updating one value using cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/683uy.png)

Comment: Share the code in script form

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer - in a nutshell: do **not** post code as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting only one record in your `select`. Cursor loops through one row provided and does your intended operation

How Cursors work:

You give the cursor some data by doing some select.
Your Cursor now loops through all the records and performs the the operation you intend to do.

Example in SqlServer:

```
DECLARE Cursor scroll cursor for 

SELECT top 500 ID, demoID, demosecondID
FROM Table  
WHERE condition = @Variable

OPEN Cursor  

fetch next from Cursor into @ID, @demoId,@demosecondId

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0  
    BEGIN  
         -- Your intended operation
         fetch next from Cursor into @ID, @demoId,@demosecondId
    END
Close Cursor  
Deallocate Cursor
```

As per your requirement, How about using simple join?

```
UPDATE
    Employee
SET
    Employee.DesignationID = Designation.DesignationID 
FROM
    Employee
INNER JOIN
    Designation
ON 
    Employee.designation= Designation.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks i understand :)

Comment: Pleased to have helped @hashimmalik :)